# How to list all the permissions requested by an extension?

Tags: privacy, browser-extensions

To install an extension, the browser (Chromium Web browser) give us an alert "**can read all data on your computer and the websites you visit**" , Sometimes we need to install an extension at least to block ADs , Is that possible to list all permissions requested by an extension? And how to change the permissions granted to an extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Menu > Settings > Extensions > Details

[image: Extension details showing permissions]

You can't change the permissions of an extension. It is assumed that the extension can't work properly without all the permissions, so allowing it some permissions and not others would break it partially.